# Mac Catalyst: original_application_version app receipt value

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, mac-app-store, mac-catalyst

I want to use the `original_application_version` value from the app receipt to grandfather some features for users who are first-time users vs existing users. In the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html), the field's notes are as follows:

```
This corresponds to the value of CFBundleVersion (in iOS) or CFBundleShortVersionString (in macOS) in the Info.plist file when the purchase was originally made.

In the sandbox environment, the value of this field is always “1.0”.
```

I'm unsure which value to expect in Mac Catalyst, since it's a UIKit (and thus iOS)-based app being distributed through the Mac App Store and run on a Mac. My instinct is that the store is determinative, and thus to expect the macOS CFBundleShortVersionString on the Mac. Unfortunately, since the value is always "1.0" in the sandbox (including TestFlight) I don't have a good way to test this.

Does anyone have any real-world experience that can shed light on what format I can expect?

Comment: My experience tells me, CFBundleShortVersionString mentions the 3rd or 4th part of version such as 1.0.0.0 or 1.0.0 try it.